# glTexImage2D causes memory leak

Tags: java, opengl, memory-leaks, lwjgl

I planned to use OpenGL to render video stream.

First step i do after receiving first frame of the video is allocating direct byte buffer and putting all the frame fragments in it. The ByteBuffer is allocated only once.

`directBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frameSize * fragmentCount);`

When all frame fragments are in place, i'm passing the ByteBuffer to OpenGL renderer

```
public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
    buffer.rewind();
    fragments.stream().forEach((frameFragment) -> {
        for (byte byteFragment : frameFragment.getFrameData()) {
            buffer.put(byteFragment);
        }
    });
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```

The blocking queue in main scene loop is waiting for frame to be ready and then renders the scene.

`ByteBuffer frame = framesQueue.take();`

Afterwards im clearing the scene, setting viewport and so on

```
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(-480, 480, -270, 270, -1, 1);
            glPushMatrix();
            glViewport(0, 0, 768, 576);
```

When it is done, im ready to draw a textured quad onto the scene.

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glGenTextures());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 768, 576, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(768, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(768, 576);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 576);
    }
    glEnd();
```

The program is running, the video is pretty smooth and has reasonably low latency (that was the main concern)

The problem is that method

```
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 768, 576, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Is causing memory to leak.

The java heapspace seems fine[image]

But the memory usage by java keeps growing infinitely.[image]

For a test, i did comment execution of

```
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 768, 576, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

method, and the memory leak did not occur. Also i tried using drawPixels method, that also helped but i think that using textures is the way to go here, not deprecated drawPixels method.

How can i solve the memory leak problem? Alternatively, what are the other, efficient, ways to display new texture on scene every 40ms. Latency is critical.

Comment: Is there any reason why you generate a new texture in each frame  instead of just uploading new data? Additionally, you are not deleting the old texture. Since the old texture remains in memory it is not surprising that the memory increases.

Comment: Using the same texID and deleting texture after rendering each frame does seem to have helped. Is it a way to go? Edit: Actually, using just 0 as tex id, without even delting the texture helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call seemed to be a problem

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glGenTextures());
```

Since im just using a single texture the call can be replaced with

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

That prevents OpenGL from creating NEW texture each call.